# Is this an appropriate use of regex and string.matches?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check if a string being passed in like "055# 444$ 285" contains any non-whitespace or digits and decided regex might be useful here (never used it before). If the string contains any non-whitespace or non-digits I want to return false.

Using regex and string.matches can I do what I want or is there another method I should use?

```
     boolean isValid(String candidate)
        {
            if(candidate.matches("[^\\d|\\s]+"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: @GurwinderSingh When I run it through my junit 
```test public void testStringContainingSymbolsInvalid() {
        assertFalse(luhnValidator.isValid("055# 444$ 285"));
    }``` it says that it's returning true. 

@ctwheels I tried that and it still fails :/ Thank you for the information though, I've reduced the code down

Comment: Use find() rather than matches(). And remove the "+" characters from your regex, because you're only looking for a single character matching the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Your current code checks to see if the entire string matches non-digit/non-whitespace/non-pipe (`|`) characters from start to finish. Change it instead to match `[\d\s]` from start to finish and return the result. The pipe is not needed in character sets for alternation (it'll match that character literally).

You can test how your current program is running by passing it the following strings:

```
!@#           # returns true
|||           # returns false
1 2           # returns false
```

---

#### Fix

You can use the following instead. It checks that the entire string matches only digits and whitespace characters:

```
return candidate.matches("[\\d\\s]+");
```

[Code sample working here](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoJAEIbP@hSDp5VIIhSC6NK9k9BFPYzuVmu6K@4oRPjstrZJpxlmvvn@qXHEbc2f81w1aAxcUCp4@143lI2swBCSLaOWHFq7Yin1Ut2zArC/m3AhvVLrRqCCERtLnUCa69KxYJckEMcx7A9JEB4tmb4MiTbSA0Wd1dCNnd1tRNqJ2VcSLvTke7/0NWAVOxQqVFxyJOHe6AUNvfpPoxapegjDgizPeZ6bYhM47zTPHw)

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean valid = isValid("055 444 285");
        System.out.printf(Boolean.toString(valid));
    }
    static boolean isValid(String candidate) {
        return candidate.matches("[\\d\\s]+");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

matches goes for the *ENTIRE* string.

You're saying:

Does the ENTIRE string fit this description:

- The first character is not a digit, not a bar, and not a whitespace.
- Then we're either at the end, or another non-digit, non-bar, non-whitespace char.
- Keep going until the end.

Obviously, "055# 444$ 285" is indeed NOT matching that regexp. Starts right at the first character: 0 is a digit.

What you want is: Is there just a single non-digit, non-space character anywhere in it? Then - invalid. So, you want `find`, not `matches`, and you don't want the plus. Presumably, you don't want the | either.